# Keras sign for if statement

Tags: keras

I have a function that I define as follows

```python
def NewLoss(y_true,y_pred):
    p=0
    for i in range(3074):
        if (y_pred[i+1]-y_pred[i])<0:
           p+=(y_true[i]-y_pred[i])**2
        elif (y_pred[i+1]-y_pred[i])>0:
           p+=(y_true[i]-y_pred[i])**2+(y_true[i]-y_pred[i])*(y_pred[i+1]-y_pred[i])**2
        else:
           p+=(y_true[i]-y_pred[i])**2+0.5*(y_true[i]-y_pred[i])*(y_pred[i+1]-y_pred[i])**2 

    return p
```

My `y_true` and `y_pred` are vectors. When I try to run a code that calls this function, I get the following error:

> "Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed".

I would like to know how to check the sign of `(y_true[i]-y_pred[i])` and avoid this error, I am actually using keras.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def NewLoss(y_true, y_pred):

    true = y_true[:3074] 
    pred = y_pred[:3074]
    predShifted = y_pred[1:3075]

    diff = true - pred
    diffShifted = predShifted - pred

    pLeftPart = K.square(diff)
    pRightPart = diff * K.square(diffShifted)

    greater = K.cast(K.greater(diffShifted,0),K.floatx())
    equal = 0.5 * K.cast(K.equal(diffShifted, 0), K.floatx())
    mask = greater + equal

    return K.sum(pLeftPart + (mask*pRightPart))
```

**Remarks:**

1 - The first axis is the samples axis, perhaps you're trying to do this with the timesteps axis? If so, use:

```
 true = y_true[:,:3074]
 pred = y_pred[:,:3074]
 predShifted = y_pred[:,1:3075]
```

2 - Having differences exactly equal to zero is so rare that maybe you don't need the last part of the if statement.

3 - If the max length of your tensors is 3075, you can simplify the selections:

```
true = y_true[:-1]
pred = y_pred[:-1]
predShifted = y_pred[1:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable help :).. It actually worked :)!